# Alternative form of ArcSin[Sin[x]]

Tags: simplifying-expressions, trigonometry

Is it possible to get the following result in Mathematica by using only built-in functions:

$$\arcsin( \sin(x)) = x $$ if $x \in [-\pi /2 , \pi/2]$

$$\arcsin ( \sin(x)) = \pi - x $$ if $x \in [\pi /2 , 3\pi/2]$

Comment: This should be reported as a bug, since `ArcSin[Sin[x]]` is correctly not simplified to `x`, whereas, as you note above, `Sin[ArcSin[x]]` is.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We can take the `Floor` and `Ceiling` from Carl's answer and expand them out:

```
PiecewiseExpand[
  PowerExpand[ArcSin[Sin[x]], Assumptions -> x ∈ Reals], 
  -π/2 < x < 3π/2
]
```

[image]

### Edit

As it turns out, we can just pass the interval into `PowerExpand`:

```
PowerExpand[ArcSin[Sin[x]], Assumptions -> -π/2 < x < 3π/2]
```

[image]

Comment: Hello @ChipHurst, can you tell me why in the second line of the output there is True instead of "-pi/2<=x<=pi/2" please?

Comment: We told `PiecewiseExpand` that our domain is restricted to `-π/2 < x < 3π/2`. Under this constraint, `x > π/2` corresponds to `π/2 < x < 3π/2` and `True` (I always read as 'otherwise' here) corresponds to `-π/2 < x <= π/2`.

Comment: thank you very much for your elegant solution.

Answer (score 5):

@kglr was on the right track with [`PowerExpand`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PowerExpand). With the default option [`Assumptions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Assumptions)->[`Automatic`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Automatic), Mathematica may return a result that is not valid. On the other hand, if you give [`PowerExpand`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PowerExpand) a non-default assumption, then it will return a result valid given those assumptions. So, for your example:

```
Assuming[
    x ∈ Reals,
    Simplify @ PowerExpand[ArcSin[Sin[x]], Assumptions -> x ∈ Reals]
]
```

> 1/2 (-1)^(Ceiling[1/2 + x/π] + Floor[-(1/2) + x/π] + 
>     Floor[1/2 + x/π]) (π + (-1)^(
>       Ceiling[1/2 + x/π] + Floor[1/2 + x/π]) π + 2 x - 
>      2 π Floor[1/2 + x/π])

Comment: Hello @CarlWoll, I have some difficult to interpret the solution. Can you explain me how it is related to the solution which I expected (the one in the question) please?

Comment: I am a bit puzzled by this solution; I would never have found it myself. My idea about `PowerExand` is that it has to do with expansion of powers and nothing with inverse trigonometric functions. Is there a mathematical or Mathematica reason that I should think of using `PowerExpand` for problems like these?

Answer (score 2):

[image]

```
FunctionPeriod[ArcSin[Sin[x]], x]

PowerExpand[ArcSin[Sin[x]], Assumptions -> 0 <= x <= 2 π]

funcs = {
   ArcSin[Sin[x]],
   π/2 TriangleWave[x/(2 π)], 
   Abs[Mod[x - π/2, 2 π] - π] - π/2, 
   With[{x = Mod[x, 2 π]}, Piecewise[{{π - x, π/2 < x <= 3 π/2}, {x, x <= π/2}}, x - 2 π]]
};

Plot[funcs + {0, 5, 10, 15} // Evaluate, {x, -20, 20}]

Table[Subtract @@@ Partition[funcs, 2, 1, 1], {x, -1000., 1000.}] // Chop // Union
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Answer to the first question

```
Simplify[x == ArcSin[Sin[x]], -Pi/2 <= x <= Pi/2]
(* True *)
```

Comment: Hello @UlrichNeumann, if possible i'd like to avoid to specify the range -Pi/2 <= x <= Pi/2. I prefer a more general statement because the above one is valid also for instance when Simplify[x == ArcSin[Sin[x]], 0 <= x <= Pi/2]

Comment: @Gennaro Arguzzi You want to prove `ArcSin[Sin[x]]=="triangle function"`?

Comment: I'm looking for built-in functions that allow me to "simplify" arcsin(sin(x)).

Answer (score 1):

An easy way is to define a new function `sin` which will work as intended:

```
sin /: (ArcSin[sin[x :(_Real | _Integer| _Rational)]]
        /;-(Pi/2)<=Mod[x, 2 Pi, -Pi/2] <= Pi/2) := x;
sin /: (ArcSin[sin[x :(_Real | _Integer| _Rational)]]
        /; Pi/2<Mod[x, 2Pi,-Pi/2] < (3 Pi)/2) := Pi - x;
sin[x_] := Sin[x];
```

I intentionally restricted to real numbers (why I used heads `Real`, `Integer`, and `Rational`) so that I can use `Mod`.

Instead of trying to convert each `Sin` to `sin`, we can automate it by

```
$Pre = Function[# /. Sin -> sin];
```

Now, we do not have to do anything: The code works as expected. For example

```
Plot[ArcSin[Sin[x]], {x, -Pi, 3 Pi}]
```

[image]