# Simplify $\tan^{-1}(\cot(a))$ to $\frac{\pi }{2}-a$ assuming $0<a<\frac{\pi }{2}$

Tags: simplifying-expressions, symbolic, trigonometry

I know *Mathematica* is not omnipotent, but still can't help feeling surprised when I encountered this example, and I think it's worth starting a question for it.

The example is, `Simplify` etc. doesn't seem to *know* `ArcTan[Cot[a]]` equals `Pi/2 - a` assuming `0 < a < Pi/2`:

```
FullSimplify[ArcTan[Cot[a]], 0 < a < Pi/2]
(* ArcTan[Cot[a]] *)

FullSimplify[ArcTan[Cot[a]] == Pi/2 - a, 0 < a < Pi/2]
(* 2 (a + ArcTan[Cot[a]]) == Pi *)
```

To make this post a question, I'd like to ask, is it possible to use `Simplify` and its friends to transform `ArcTan[Cot[a]]` to `Pi/2 - a`? Say in advance, I don't want to use `Series`:

```
Series[ArcTan[Cot[a]], {a, 0, 1}] // Normal
(* -a + Pi/2 *)
```

BTW, *Maple* can simplify it:

[image]

Comment: To the downvoter, I am interested in what's wrong with my question, would you please elaborate. I'm not trying to complain here, I just want improve my question if possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Similar to the answer [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/185490/4346), we can use `PowerExpand`.

```
PowerExpand[ArcTan[Cot[a]], Assumptions -> 0 < a < π/2]
```

> ```
> π/2 - a
> ```

In fact an almost identical example appears in the `PowerExpand` ref page [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PowerExpand#42804783).

[image]

Comment: Oh… believe it or not, I read your answer yesterday and even scaned the document page of `PowerExpand` for a while, but simply didn't notice that's the solution for my question…

Answer (score 2):

```
Reduce[{ArcTan[Cot[a]] - Pi/2 + a == 0, a > 0, a < Pi/2}, a, Reals]
```

> 0 < a < π/2

The answer means the inequalities `a > 0, a < Pi/2` imply the relation `ArcTan[Cot[a]] - Pi/2 + a == 0`.

The second answer is as follows.

```
Simplify[D[ArcTan[Cot[x]] - Pi/2 + x, x], Assumptions -> x > 0 && x < Pi/2]
```

> 0

implies `ArcTan[Cot[x]] - Pi/2 + x` is a constant on the interval $(0,\pi/2)$. It remains

```
ArcTan[Cot[x]] - Pi/2 + x /. x -> Pi/4
```

> 0

to prove the identity.

Comment: @xzczd: Don't hesitate to ask for further explanation in need.

Comment: I believe I've fully understood your answer :)

Comment: @xzczd: So you may accept it.

Comment: Well, this answer is still a little away from the goal of my question, I'm afraid. Currently your answer show 2 ways to **verify** the identity (the second sample can be extended a bit of course e.g. `DSolve[{y'[x] == D[ArcTan[Cot[x]], x], y[Pi/4] == ArcTan[Cot[Pi/4]]}, y[x], x]`), but my goal is, as said above, "use `Simplify` and its friends to transform  `ArcTan[Cot[a]]` to `Pi/2 - a`". Ideally I'd like to see an answer based on combination of `Simplify`, `Expand`, etc., together with some clever  option settings e.g. `TransformationFunctions`.

Comment: @xzczd: I got your point.

Answer (score 1):

**THIS IS AN EXTENDED COMMENT RATHER THAN AN ANSWER**

The problem appears to be systemic

```
Assuming[0 < a < Pi/2, ArcTan[Cot[a]] == (Pi/2 - a) // FullSimplify]

(* 2 (a + ArcTan[Cot[a]]) == π *)
```

More troubling since [`PossibleZeroQ`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PossibleZeroQ.html) uses both "basic symbolic and numerical methods"

```
PossibleZeroQ[ArcTan[Cot[a]] - (Pi/2 - a), 
  Assumptions -> 0 < a < Pi/2]

(* False *)
```

Comment: Er… I think `Assuming[assumption, FullSimplify[expr]]` is just the same as `FullSimplify[expr, assumption]`? Is there any example in which these 2 approaches give differenct results?

Comment: @xzczd - The two forms are equivalent. The main point I was making is that `PossibleZeroQ` was unable to symbolically or numerically conclude that `ArcTan[Cot[a]] - (Pi/2 - a)` was zero on the interval {0, Pi/2} and even worse concluded that it was NOT zero.

Answer (score 1):

I like very much the answer of @user64494 using Reduce. However, its use requires to apriori know the result. The latter is known in the present expression, but in more complex cases can be unknown. For this reason, I am giving now a more lengthy way, avoiding an in-advance knowing of the result.

The core problem here is that the functions `Simplify` and `FullSimplify` do not efficiently work on logarithms. I will first introduce two my own functions to work with the logarithms. One of them, called "collectLog" transforms the sum (or difference) of logarithms into the logarithm of the product (or ratio). The second "expandLog" acts in the opposite way.

```
expandLog[expr_] := Module[{rule1, rule2, a, b, x, g},
   rule1 = Log[a_*b_] -> Log[a] + Log[b];
   rule2 = Log[a_^x_] -> x*Log[a];
   g[x_] := (x /. rule1) /. rule2;
   FixedPoint[g, expr]
   ];

collectLog[expr_] := Module[{rule1a, rule1b, rule2, g, a, b, x},
   rule1a = Log[a_] + Log[b_] -> Log[a*b];
   rule1b = Log[a_] - Log[b_] -> Log[a/b];
   rule2 = x_*Log[a_] -> Log[a^x];
   g[x_] := x /. rule1a /. rule1b /. rule2;
   FixedPoint[g, expr]
   ];
```

With this let us first define the expression:

```
expr1 = ArcTan[Cot[a]];
```

and apply the the function `TrigToExp` to it:

```
expr2 = TrigToExp[expr1] // Factor
(*  1/2 I (Log[1 - (E^(-I a) + E^(I a))/(E^(-I a) - E^(I a))] - 
   Log[1 + (E^(-I a) + E^(I a))/(E^(-I a) - E^(I a))])  *)
```

The second part of the `expr2` contains the difference of two logarithms and it is reasonable to apply `collectLog` to it:

```
expr3 = MapAt[Simplify[collectLog[#]] &, expr2, 2]

(* 1/2 I Log[-E^(2 I a)] *)
```

It is now reasonable to transform `-1` into either `Exp[I Pi]`, or `Exp[-I Pi]`. The second case will yield the answer you give in the question:

```
expr4 = expr3 /. -E^(2 I a) -> E^(2 I a - I \[Pi])

(* 1/2 I Log[E^(2 I a - I \[Pi])] *)
```

Now expanding the logarithm staying in the second position in the `expr4` we obtain the answer:

```
MapAt[expandLog, expr4, 2] // Expand

(* -a + \[Pi]/2*)
```

Have fun!

Comment: Well, this solution is dangerous, isn't it? The condition `0 < a < Pi/2` is not used…

Comment: @xzczd It is implicitly used when the transformation `-1->Exp[-I Pi]` has been chosen. But I agree with you.