# Does Mathematica know about identity involving ArcSin(Cos(x))?

Tags: simplifying-expressions, trigonometry

Given that $0 < x < \pi/2$, it can be shown that $$\arcsin(\cos(x)) = \pi/2-x,$$ however, I was unable to make Mathematica to simplify the LHS into the RHS. I was guessing that,

```
Simplify[ArcSin[Cos[x]],Assumptions -> {0 < x < Pi/2}]
```

would have done the trick, but Mathematica seems to be reluctant on manipulating this expression at all, so I was starting to wonder if it knows about these kinds of identities in the first place?

Since the relation is proven from the general $$\arcsin(x)+\arccos(x) = \pi/2,$$
I was thinking at first that the issue might be evaluating $\arccos(\cos(x))$. However, this can be done using PowerExpand, which does not help in the case of $\arcsin(\cos(x))$ though?

Comment: Probably need `FullSimplify` with a custom `ComplexityFunction`. `ArcSin[Cos[x]]` has a `LeafCount` of only 3, so it's about as simple as you can get.

Comment: This is valid for `0<x<Pi`. Maples gets it: `simplify(arcsin(cos(x))) assuming 0<x,x<Pi
` gives `Pi/2 - x`  ![Mathematica graphics](http://i.stack.imgur.com/qfXfn.png)  As mentioned in comment above, you probably need to use custom complexityfunction for this in Mathematica.

Comment: Strongly related, if not a duplicate. [Alternative form of ArcSin\[Sin\[x\]\]](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/185468/alternative-form-of-arcsinsinx)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [`PowerExpand`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PowerExpand):

```
PowerExpand[ArcSin[Cos[x]], Assumptions -> 0 < x < π/2]
```

> π/2 - x

Comment: This works. I am confused as I am certain I did try this beforehand... Anyway, thank you.

Comment: Didn't work with $arccos(-cos(x))$